# Googel Apps Script - API Query - XML Parse and Loop add to rows of a Sheet?

Tags: xml, loops, google-apps-script

I have a API query bringing back xml like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <computers>
    <size>3830</size>
    <computer>
      <id>6</id>
      <name>A user </name>
      <managed>false</managed>
      <username/>
      <model>Computer 1</model>
      <department/>
      <building/>
      <mac_address>78:4F:XXXXX</mac_address>
      <udid>A3E2C80A-XXXXX</udid>
      <serial_number>C02TGXXXX</serial_number>
      <report_date_utc>2022-04-19T13:23:00.404+0000</report_date_utc>
      <report_date_epoch>165037458XXX</report_date_epoch>
    </computer>
    <computer>
      <id>13</id>
      <name>C1MRXXXX</name>
      <managed>true</managed>
      <username>my.user</username>
      <model>Mac</model>
      <department/>
      <building/>
      <mac_address>98:01:XXXXXX</mac_address>
      <udid>A4177C40-0B6B-57CD-932A-XXXXXX</udid>
      <serial_number>C1MRV3XXXXXX</serial_number>
      <report_date_utc>2022-09-21T14:07:19.421+0000</report_date_utc>
      <report_date_epoch>1663769239421</report_date_epoch>
    </computer>
```

I'm trying to get some of that XML data into a Google Sheet.

The script I have works for the first set of data between `<computer> </computer>` and I get my selected items as a row in my Sheet :)

But how do I make it loop through all the output data and add a new row for each selection within `<computer> </computer>`?

This is my script.

```
function GetMyData() {

//Query jamf 
  var url = 'https://MYSERVER.mydomain.com/computers/subset/basic';
  var myXml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Basic ENCODED_BASIC_CREDS_HERE",
      
      "Content-Type": "application/xml"
    },
  }).getContentText();

  var document = XmlService.parse(myXml);
  var root = document.getRootElement();

  //set variables to data from myXml
  var id = root.getChild('computer').getChild('id').getText();
  var name = root.getChild('computer').getChild('name').getText();
  var managed = root.getChild('computer').getChild('managed').getText();
  var username = root.getChild('computer').getChild('username').getText();
  var model = root.getChild('computer').getChild('model').getText();
  var serial_number = root.getChild('computer').getChild('serial_number').getText();

  // Populate sheet with variable data
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1).setValue(id);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,2).setValue(name);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,3).setValue(managed);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,4).setValue(username);  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,5).setValue(model);  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,6).setValue(serial_number);  

  // Logger items
  Logger.log(id);
  Logger.log(name);
  Logger.log(managed);
  Logger.log(username);
  Logger.log(model);
  Logger.log(serial_number);
  
}
```

Comment: Check out the [XmlService documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service). There are code snippets there that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

```js
  //your query

  var document = XmlService.parse(myXml)
  var root = document.getRootElement()
  var computers = root.getChildren("computer")
  var list=[]

  computers.forEach(function(item){
    var computer=[]
    item.getChildren().forEach(function(details){
      computer.push(details.getValue())
    })
    list.push(computer)
  })

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list)
```

And the result (I added the headers manually):
[image]

This grabs all the `<computer>` nodes and loops through its children to build a 2d array, then uses [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) to write everything to the sheet at once. Google recommends using batch operations in their [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations) to improve performance. Writing each value from a file that could contain thousands of rows would be very slow compared to writing them from an array. Also, the range is being selected dynamically with [`getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()) so you can just keep feeding XML files to the script and they'll be added at the end.

If you only want certain values from each `<computer>` node you can specify them manually and replace the second loop.

Comment: Whoa! thats great...Thank you.

Comment: Hope this helps. If this solves your issue please consider marking this as accepted so others with similar questions can benefit.